# How to Convert BsonDocument.ToJson() to camelCase

Tags: c#, json.net, mongodb-.net-driver

I currently have a JSON.NET ContractResolver and I've created a BsonDocument JsonConverter.

My ContractResolver uses CreateContract and sets the Converter to my custom BsonDocumentJsonConverter when `type==typeof(BsonDocument)`

The JsonConverter looks like this:

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var json = ((BsonDocument) value).ToJson();
        writer.WriteRawValue(camelCase);
    }
```

Without this custom converter the JSON that JSON.NET returns for the BsonDocument looks more like a dictionary {"name":"foo","value":"bar"} than the true shape {foo:"bar"}.

The problem is that i can't seem to figure out how to get the BsonDocument to be serialized in camelcase, or how to have the ContractResolver double back over my return and apply the NamingStrategy.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It's confusing question. You ask about camelCase when described problem is not about camelCase.

Comment: @rnofenko it is about camelCase -- i want to serialize the BsonDocument to camelCase